# Why does the process ID change in the output of "ps -l"?

Tags: process, background-process

Whenever I run a command in the terminal on Linux, at runtime, its PID changes.

[image]

The command I used after running one program two times at runtime, was `ps -l`. Why does the program change process ID?

Comment: To expand on what @roaima said in the answer submitted, you are not checking the PID of the *same* process. Your are executing a NEW process (in the background, thanks to the & character) each time you put in the command and hit enter. Since they are separate processes, of course they need separate PIDs.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each new process (and each new instance of the same named program) has a new Process IDentifier.

The PID is an integer, and when it gets to its maximum value it wraps around back to 1. The PID value (number) is unique for any moment in time.

Comment: Even tho we are running a same program?

Comment: @SawakoKuronuma in your example you are running the same program twice so you have a unique PID for each instance. What is not clear about user roaima's answer?

Comment: Just asking whether an id would change if the same program is run at same time,,,nvm Got the anwer already,,thanku.

Comment: FWIW, I think Linux may allow PIDs up to 2^22 (PID_MAX_LIMIT).  By default it may be 32768, but that can be changed.  MacOS definitely has PIDs over 65535.

Comment: @StephenHarris thank you. Didn't know about `PID_MAX_LIMIT`.

Comment: @roaima, ok, good :)

Answer (score 0):

Pid - is process id
Ppid - is parent process id
When you run your program, it gets his own pid, therefore pid changes when you run programm some times. Ppid is not changes, because parent process for program is terminal, from which you ran programs

Maybe parent is not terminal, but your programs has one parent for all, and therefore ppid is not changed